# Update Application via WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, installation

I've an application that reads from an online database the current version of the application itself, when I make some changes to the application I use to create a new msi setup and put it on my server, than I change the version inside the database and when the application starts it notices that there is a newer version and asks to the user for the update. During the update it downloads the msi file and it launchs it after the download: now the problem.. when the user tries to install the new version a popup message appears saying that another version of the software is already installed in and it can't overwrite it! Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried to go down this road before, trust me when I say this... find a popular deployment tool and use it. The headache of attempting to have your application self-update is not worth it. Personally, my issues with UAC frustrated me enough to just give up going down that road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem using WIX

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using ClickOnce deployment?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx

Comment: There are some feature that ClickOnce does not cover like the installation conditions

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a desktop application, and integrated the project output in Install shield setup wizard. every time I deploy the setup for installation. I face the error as specified by @ThomasSquall.

While uninstalling the existing installed app, we need use the same source .exe used for installing not the updated version source .exe.